# DB2 sql query to avoid permutation combination of result with multiple "in clause"

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to fetch data (color) from table 'X' for model and yr combination.

```
model     yr      color
a        2007    yellow,black
b        2008    yellow,orange,pink
```

so for `(a,2007)` it should return `yellow,black`

```
SELECT * from X where model in (a,b) and yr in (2007,2008)
```

=> returns all combinations

I tried

```
SELECT * from X where (model,yr) in (VALUES(a,2007),(b,2008))
```

=> query is not getting executed. syntax error.

What should I do?

Comment: What is the syntax error and what DB2 are you using?

Comment: ... `where (model = 'a' and year = 2007) or (model = 'b' and year = 2008)` ?

Answer (score 2):

The following should return the desired result. Have you used quotes around the string constants?

```
select color from foo where (model,yr) in (values ('a',2007),('b',2008))
```

Comment: Yes, I did. getting error Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-216, SQLSTATE=428C4, SQLERRMC==, DRIVER=3.57.82
SQLState:  428C4
ErrorCode: -216
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=3.57.82
SQLState:  26501
ErrorCode: -514

Comment: Error -216 says that your predicate has the wrong number of elements on each side. Are you executing the exact same query?

Comment: select * from foo where (mdl_cd,mdl_yr) in  (VALUES(5338,2016),(9234,2017));

Comment: I am using Squirrel SQL client

Comment: Please add the table definition and other helpful info. The syntax should work. The error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on variants of DB2 (LUW,ZOS,AS400) you may have to use either `VALUES` or `SYSDUMMY1` table.

The solution for DB2 zOS is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE (model,yr) IN 
(SELECT a,2007 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
 UNION 
 SELECT b,2008 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
```

If you wish to pass a set of `model,year` tuples parameters, you can use the `XMLTABLE` function to parse an XML parameter into a synthetic table.

```
SELECT * FROM x WHERE (model,yr) IN 
(select "model","year" from 
 param,xmltable(
 '$Q/q/r' PASSING ? AS "Q"
 columns
 "model" varchar(30) path '@model',
 "year" integer path '@year'
 ) AS "Q"
)
```

The query would have the form of

```html
<q>
<r model="a" year="2007" />
<r model="b" year="2008" />
</q>
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution :

```
select * 
from foo t1 
inner join table (values ('a',2007),('b',2008)) t2(Key1, key2) 
on (t1.model, t1.yr)=(t2.Key1, t2.Key2)
```